# Whats the female equivalent of "a man for all seasons"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the female equivalent of "a man for all seasons"?

Comment: A woman for all seasons.

Answer (score 2):

> A woman for all seasons

It's not a common phrase in the same way, but it's the female equivalent

Answer (score 2):

While "a woman for all seasons" is probably the simplest answer because it easily switches, it's not an "accepted phrase". Though I haven't heard "a man for all seasons" in quite some time personally.

There are a few alternate phrases with similar meanings to look at.

1. Jack-of-all-trades - It's generally believed that this term can be used for men and women, and doesn't really have a gender connection behind it, despite Jack being a man's name. This does have more negative connotations than "man for all seasons" due to the phrase "Jack-of-all-trades, master of none".
2. Renaissance woman - again, this is a gender change from "Renaissance Man" and therefore pretty similar to the "man/woman for all seasons" problem mentioned above.
3. You could change it slightly and say that the woman is "versatile", "multi-talented", "dependable" or something else that doesn't bring in any gender at all.