# CAN WE SAY THAT SHE IS A MAN IN "She is a man of character."

Tags: grammatical-gender

I'd like to express the full sentence: *She looks quite thin, but in fact she is a man of character.* Can we apply the expression a man of character when a woman has a strong character?

Comment: No. It sounds just as awkward to everyone else.

Comment: Why say she is a man when in fact she's a woman.....we don't usually say she is a man unless discussing gender issues and someone is saying that. But certainly the thin and of character wouldn't work there.

Comment: Please, tell me how to say that she looks a small girl , but in fact she has a strong character in more beautiful way in 1 sentence?)))

Comment: I think you want to say that she looks frail but that she has the character of a man.  But that's problematic for two reasons.  The first is that physical weakness is not an indication of strength of character.  Secondly, why should the character of a man be more praiseworthy than the character of a woman?  Perhaps *She may look quite small and childlike, but she has an adult's strength of character.*

Comment: Set expressions of the form "a man of ____" can't be applied to women. Unfortunately, there is no simple process for forming equivalent female expressions. The following questions are examples: [Gender-neutral equivalent of “Man of the world”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288670), [Whats the female equivalent of “a man for all seasons”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278983)

Comment: *She looks quite thin, but in fact she is [a woman of substance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+woman+of+substance%22)*

Comment: "Woman of character" is a correct expression. Also *woman of temperament* or *strong lady*.

Comment: It should be noted, though, that saying something like "She's a better man than anyone else in the room" is occasionally said, with complementary intent, to indicate that the woman has great courage or other such "manly" attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Unless specifically wanting to address gender variability, the contradiction of using she/man or he/woman should be avoided.

> She is a woman of character.

However, this can be simply solved by using gender-neutral nouns.

> She is a person of character.

Both are acceptable and readily understood.

More to the point though, it seems that you want to give this particular sentiment:

> She is a person of substance.
>   She is a deep person.
>   She is a person of conviction and strength.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. How can you explain the expression  A PERSON OF SUBSTANCE? What's the difference between this saying and the expression A PERSON OF CHARACTER?

Comment: A "person of substance" is mostly used to indicate a person conducts life with meaningful intentions.  This person would deal with big issues and would not be vain or ineffectual.  A "person of character" refers more specifically to moral standards.  Such a person would be honest, forthright, earnest, and law-abiding.  Both terms are very subjective and mean something different depending on the person who reads/hears it.